# Is there a way to generate 25 buttons while incrementing their "onclick" function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a web page with 25 buttons and I realize the code looks to repetitive and there has to be a better way to code this. Is there a way to recreate this code with JavaScript where it generates the buttons while incrementing [i] in onclick=pic[i] and Unit [i]?

```
<div class="units">
<button type="submit" onclick="pic1()">Unit 1</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic2()">Unit 2</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic3()">Unit 3</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic4()">Unit 4</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic5()">Unit 5</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic6()">Unit 6</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic7()">Unit 7</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic8()">Unit 8</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic9()">Unit 9</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic10()">Unit 10</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic11()">Unit 11</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic12()">Unit 12</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic13()">Unit 13</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic14()">Unit 14</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic15()">Unit 15</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic16()">Unit 16</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic17()">Unit 17</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic18()">Unit 18</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic19()">Unit 19</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic20()">Unit 20</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic21()">Unit 21</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic22()">Unit 22</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic23()">Unit 23</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic24()">Unit 24</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="pic25()">Unit 25</button>
</div> <br>
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 25 different functions, but it would make more sense to me to have the `onclick` call `pic(number)`. I will assume you have already written the `pic` function.

```
// Select the `units` element that needs the buttons.
const units = document.querySelector('.units');

for (let buttonCount = 0; buttonCount < 25; buttonCount++) {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => pic(buttonCount));
  button.textContent = `Unit ${buttonCount + 1}`;
  units.appendChild(button);
}
```

If you absolutely have to, you could use:

```
button.setAttribute('onclick', `pic${buttonCount + 1}()`);
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like you'd need a separate function for each button, but if you must, you could do it like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.units').innerHTML = (
  Array.from({ length: 25 }, (_, i) => (`
    <button type="submit" onclick="pic${i + 1}()">Unit ${i + 1}</button>
  `)).join('')
)
```

```html
<div class="units"></div>
```

I'd strongly recommend that you instead define a single `pic` function that takes the item number as an argument. This will save you a lot of keystrokes when you scale up to a billion buttons.

```js
function pic(which) {
  // do stuff with whichever pic is specified by "which"
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pic(11)">Unit 11</button>
<button onclick="pic(12)">Unit 12</button>
<button onclick="pic(13)">Unit 13</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and concatenate the counter to the string "pic" is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for`-loop to iterate over your button creation. Use `createElement` for creating your button, `textContent` for setting the content and `addEventListener` for your click-functionality. Don't forget to add your new button in the DOM with `appendChild` to your DIV.
**Note:** I added for example the function pic1, the other 24 function you could write your own. But it woul be much better to use 1 function for all with parameter for this.

```js
let units = document.getElementsByClassName('units')[0];

for (let i=1; i<=25; i++) {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.textContent = 'Unit ' + i;
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() { eval('pic'+i+'();'); });
  units.appendChild(btn);
}

function pic1() {
  console.log('PIC1');
}
```

```html
<div class="units"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are fine, but what I wouldn't do (as others noticed as well) is to create a new function for every button.

I would advise changing the div to id='units' rather than the class as this seems to be a container for a single usage per page as if it was used with class I would assume you would want to do this on each of the containers, so you would have to getElementsByClass which returns an array and then loop through each and then loop through 1 through 25 to append buttons.
It didn't seem to me that is what you were doing, so this mentioned change is advised.

Firstly it might break your code if you are missing a function and the button is supposed to be mapping to it and secondly it is just poor practice honestly.

What I would do in your place is something like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="units">
    append buttons here
    </div>

    <script>
      function onClickEvent(i) {
        switch (parseInt(i)) {
          case 1:
             console.log('do this at 1')
            break
          case 2: 
            console.log('do this at 2')
            break
          default: 
            console.log('do this by default')
            break
        }
      }
      
      const divEl = document.getElementById('units')
      for (i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
        const btn = document.createElement('button')
        btn.innerText = `Unit ${i}`
        btn.value = i
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => onClickEvent(btn.value))
        divEl.appendChild(btn)
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ofcourse there are some things that can be improved here like adding a textNode to the button rather than doing the innerText I belive, but I haven't played around in DOM for a while now, so I would leave that up to you.