# Is there a way to generate 25 functions while incrementing them instead of writing each one?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to have this entire code be generated by a for loop? or another better option while incrementing the name of the function pic[i] and the names of the two files reading_[i]  & track_[i]?

```
    function pic1()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "images/reading_1.JPG";
        document.getElementById("aud").src ="audio/track_1.mp3";
    }
    function pic2()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src ="images/reading_2.JPG";
        document.getElementById("aud").src ="audio/track_2.mp3";
        
    } 
    function pic3()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "images/reading_3.JPG";
        document.getElementById("aud").src ="audio/track_3.mp3";
    }
//.......
//all the way to pic25()
//.....
   
    function pic25()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src ="images/reading_25.JPG";
        document.getElementById("aud").src ="audio/track_25.mp3";
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need separate functions? Can you make the number a parameter to the function and just have one function?

Comment: How do you intend to use these?

Comment: @charlietfl I have 25 buttons, and for each button a user clicks a unique image & audio appear.

Comment: Show us sample of the html for the buttons. Using a data attribute on each or it's value will simplify this. The answers you are getting are overkill

Comment: Can you have one function that takes a parameter -- which is the interval / number? Similar to the loops mentioned in some answers, but I don't think the loop is really needed here. (Edit: Mike says this above.)

Comment: @sterling128 ... this task can be solved with exactly one function that serves as event handler to any button. just build your buttons in a way that each button can identify itself by the right e.g. number/index or whatever your task needs.

Comment: @charlietfl I posted the HTML in another question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852914/is-there-a-way-to-generate-25-buttons-while-incrementing-their-onclick-functio/63853009#63853009)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer provided in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63853078/11619647), just creating a single `pic` function and giving it a parameter to allow the `buttonCount` to be passed would solve it.

It creates the URLs for the image and audio sources by concatenating the strings with the `buttonCount` value.

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById("img");
const audioElement = document.getElementById("aud");

function pic(buttonCount) {
  imageElement.src = `images/reading_${buttonCount}.JPG`;
  audioElement.src = `audio/track_${buttonCount}.mp3`;
}
```

Comment: How would this work with this HTML? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852914/is-there-a-way-to-generate-25-buttons-while-incrementing-their-onclick-functio/63853009#63853009)

Comment: @sterling128 Really all you need from that solution is understanding how to create the function `pic(buttonCount)`. @ExplosionPills already gave you what you are asking for again in this question. You could have just asked for clarification how to use `pic(buttonCount)`

Comment: @sterling128 I've revised my answer based on your latest input. For future reference, include all data and code that is relevant to your question without referencing other threads, even if they are yours. It will only increase your chance of getting a solid answer and makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

What one might really want is kind of a component that can be reused. Thus one would start with writing the proper markup for it, which also means that due to the generic nature of initializing such a component one also does not want to rely on any HTML element's `id` attribute at least not for both the initialization and the event handling.

Talking about the latter, changing track state for each button click one does rely on exactly a single implementation of it. This function serves as event handler for click events that are caught/delegated by the grouping parent element of any button. Thus the functionality has to assure explicitly that it does respond just to those click events that were triggered originally by button click events.

The markup of any button does provide the information about a button's related/targeted track via a buttons `data` attribute. This attribute will be read by the event handler that takes further care of this information.

Since the event handler has almost all information at hand it should not be bothered with querying the related/corresponding image/audio element again and again. This query task should be part of the player initialization as well.

Thus for every player component one does add exactly one event handler which will be a specific version of the single handler's implementation with the correct context data (image/audio elements) bound to it ...

```js
function handleTrackChangeForBoundPlayback(evt) {
  // due to player-component being a <form/>
  evt.preventDefault(); 

  const targetElm = evt.target;
  if (targetElm.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {

    const trackId = targetElm.dataset.trackId;

    // this.visualElm.src = `images/reading_${ trackId }.jpg`;
    // this.audioElm.src = `audio/track_${ trackId }.mp3`;

    this.visualElm.textContent = `images/reading_${ trackId }.jpg`;
    this.audioElm.textContent = `audio/track_${ trackId }.mp3`;
  }
}

function initializePlayer() {
  // initialize event handling for any player-component,
  document.body
    .querySelectorAll('.player')
    .forEach(playerElm => {

      const playbackElm = playerElm.querySelector('.playback');
      const visualElm = playbackElm.querySelector('.playback-visual');
      const audioElm = playbackElm.querySelector('.playback-audio');

      const optionsElm = playerElm.querySelector('.track-list');
      optionsElm.addEventListener('click', handleTrackChangeForBoundPlayback.bind({
        visualElm,
        audioElm
      }));
    });
}

initializePlayer();
```

```css
.player {
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  padding: 4px 16px 0 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
ol {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure class="player">
  <div class="playback">
    <!--
      <img class='playback-visual' src='...'/>
      <audio class='playback-audio' src='...'/>
    //-->
    <div class='playback-visual'>...</div>
    <div class='playback-audio'>...</div>
  </div>
  <ol class="track-list">
    <li><button data-track-id='1'>Track 1</button></li>
    <li><button data-track-id='2'>Track 2</button></li>
    <li><button data-track-id='3'>Track 3</button></li>
    <li>... ... ...</li>
    <li><button data-track-id='24'>Track 24</button></li>
    <li><button data-track-id='25'>Track 25</button></li>
  </ol>
</figure>

<figure class="player">
  <div class="playback">
    <!--
      <img class='playback-visual' src='...'/>
      <audio class='playback-audio' src='...'/>
    //-->
    <div class='playback-visual'>...</div>
    <div class='playback-audio'>...</div>
  </div>
  <ol class="track-list">
    <li><button data-track-id='1'>Track 1</button></li>
    <li><button data-track-id='2'>Track 2</button></li>
    <li><button data-track-id='3'>Track 3</button></li>
    <li>... ... ...</li>
    <li><button data-track-id='24'>Track 24</button></li>
    <li><button data-track-id='25'>Track 25</button></li>
  </ol>
</figure>
```

As I got aware now [from the excepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854507/is-there-a-way-to-generate-25-functions-while-incrementing-them-instead-of-writi/63855065#63854687), there was [a related previous question to the OP's current one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852914/is-there-a-way-to-generate-25-buttons-while-incrementing-their-onclick-functio) which, of cause, changes the entire picture.

The use case of *"... generating 25 buttons while incrementing their `onclick` function."* does relate much more to an entire dynamically built component.

Thus the above provided first approach has to shift to less initially provided markup in favor of generating it most favorable based on some configuration data ...

```js
const PlayerComponent = (function () {

  function parseTrackIdTemplate(pathTemplate, trackId) {
    return pathTemplate.replace((/\$\{\s*trackId\s*\}/), trackId);
  }

  function handleTrackChangeForBoundPlayback(evt) {
    const targetElm = evt.target;
    if (targetElm.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {

      const trackId = targetElm.dataset.trackId;

      this.visualElm.textContent = parseTrackIdTemplate(this.visualPathTemplate, trackId);
      this.audioElm.textContent = parseTrackIdTemplate(this.audioPathTemplate, trackId);
    }
  }
  function initializeTrackChangeHandling(elmNode, visualElm, audioElm, config) {
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', handleTrackChangeForBoundPlayback.bind({
      visualPathTemplate: config.imagePath,
      audioPathTemplate: config.audioPath,
      visualElm,
      audioElm
    }));
  }

  function createComponentConfig(rootElm) {
    let config = Object.assign({}, rootElm.dataset);
    if (Object.keys(config).length >= 1) {

      config.trackIdList = config.trackIdList.split(/\s*,\s*/);
    } else {
      config = null;
    }
    return config;
  }

  function createTrackListItem(trackId, labelTemplate) {
    const itemElm = document.createElement('li');
    const trackElm = document.createElement('button');

    trackElm.dataset.trackId = trackId;
    trackElm.textContent = parseTrackIdTemplate(labelTemplate, trackId);

    itemElm.appendChild(trackElm);
    return itemElm;
  }
  function createTrackListComponent(config) {
    return config.trackIdList.reduce((elmNode, trackId) => {

      elmNode.appendChild(
        createTrackListItem(trackId, config.trackIdLabel)
      );
      return elmNode;

    }, document.createElement('ol'));
  }

  function createAppendAndInitializeSubComponents(rootElm) {
    const config = createComponentConfig(rootElm);
    if (config !== null) {

      const playbackElm = document.createElement('div');
      // const visualElm = document.createElement('img');
      // const audioElm = document.createElement('audio');

      const visualElm = document.createElement('div');
      const audioElm = document.createElement('div');
      visualElm.textContent = '...';
      audioElm.textContent = '...';

      playbackElm.className = 'playback';
      visualElm.className = 'playback-visual';
      audioElm.className = 'playback-audio';

      const trackListElm = createTrackListComponent(config);

      initializeTrackChangeHandling(trackListElm, visualElm, audioElm, config);
      trackListElm.className = 'track-list';

      playbackElm.appendChild(visualElm);
      playbackElm.appendChild(audioElm);

      rootElm.appendChild(playbackElm);
      rootElm.appendChild(trackListElm);
    }
  }

  function initializePlayer() {
    // initialize any player-component.
    document.body
      .querySelectorAll('.player-component')
      .forEach(createAppendAndInitializeSubComponents);
  }

  return {
    initialize: initializePlayer
  };
}());


PlayerComponent.initialize();
```

```css
.player-component {
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  padding: 4px 16px 0 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
ol {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure
  class="player-component"
  data-track-id-label="Track ${ trackId }"
  data-track-id-list="1,2,3,15,16,17,24,25"
  data-audio-path="audio/track_${ trackId }.mp3"
  data-image-path="images/reading_${ trackId }.jpg"
></figure>

<figure
  class="player-component"
  data-track-id-label="Track ${ trackId }"
  data-track-id-list="21,22,23,24,25"
  data-audio-path="other/audio/track-${ trackId }.mp3"
  data-image-path="other/images/track-${ trackId }.jpg"
></figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let function_obj = {};

for (let i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
  function_obj['pic' + i] = () => {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "images/reading_" + i + ".JPG";
    document.getElementById("aud").src = "audio/track_" + i + ".mp3";
  }
}
```

You could do it as above. The above code snippet will create 25 functions which you can access as `function_obj.pic1()`, `function_obj.pic2()`, and so on...

Although the above method would do the job you have asked for, it's not a good programming approach. Whatever you are trying to do can be done in a more optimal way or approach without needing to create 25 functions.

One way I can think of is create a general `pic` function and just pass the parameter of the string for src of elements with id - `img` and `aud` or even just pass the numbers as parameters and just form the string of path inside the function. This can be done with just one function instead of having to repeat it over 25 functions.

Comment: Any modification/suggestion or better approach is appreciated to the one who downvoted my answer

Comment: Although It's kind of what OP asked, I don't think that you should *actually* create 25 functions which do the same thing. It's just bad programming.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes, I have modified my answer to include further explanation as well

Comment: You've taken OP's request to create 25 functions too literally. Agree that this is not a normal approach for something like this

Comment: @charlietfl I have just mentioned a way of doing it without writing 25 functions manually. Also, If you read my last two para of answers, I have mentioned a better approach which would do the same job using a single function. That seems a pretty good approach of doing it